# python requests randomly breaks with JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been debugging for hours why my code randomly breaks with this error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

This is the code I have:

```
while True:
    try:
        submissions = requests.get('http://reymisterio.net/data-dump/api.php/submission?filter[]=form,cs,'+client+'&filter[]=date,cs,'+since).json()['submission']['records']
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        time.sleep(100)
```

And I've been debugging by printing `requests.get(url)` and `requests.get(url).text` and I have encountered the following "special "cases:

1. `requests.get(url)` returns a successful 200 response and `requests.get(url).text` returns html. I have read online that this should fail when using `requests.get(url).json()`, because it won't be able to read the html, but somehow it doesn't break. Why is this?
2. `requests.get(url)` returns a successful 200 response and `requests.get(url).text` is in json format. I don't understand why when it goes to the `requests.get(url).json()` line it breaks with the JSONDecodeError?

The exact value of `requests.get(url).text` for case 2 is:

```
{
  "submission": {
    "columns": [
      "pk",
      "form",
      "date",
      "ip"
    ],
    "records": [
      [
        "21197",
        "mistico-form-contacto-form",
        "2018-09-21 09:04:41",
        "186.179.71.106"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: does it work when you try `json.loads(requests.get(url).text)`?

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the [documentation](http://reymisterio.net/data-dump/api.php) for this API it seems the only responses are in JSON format, so receiving HTML is strange. To increase the likelihood of receiving a JSON response, you can set the 'Accept' header to 'application/json'.

I tried querying this API many times with parameters and did not encounter a `JSONDecodeError`. This error is likely the result of another error on the server side. To handle it, `except` a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` in addition to the `ConnectionError` error you currently `except` and handle this error in the same way as the `ConnectionError`.

Here is an example with all that in mind:

```
import requests, json, time, random

def get_submission_records(client, since, try_number=1):
    url = 'http://reymisterio.net/data-dump/api.php/submission?filter[]=form,cs,'+client+'&filter[]=date,cs,'+since
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
        time.sleep(2**try_number + random.random()*0.01) #exponential backoff
        return get_submission_records(client, since, try_number=try_number+1)
    else:
        return response['submission']['records']
```

I've also wrapped this logic in a recursive function, rather than using `while` loop because I think it is semantically clearer. This function also waits before trying again using exponential backoff (waiting twice as long after each failure).

**Edit:** For Python 2.7, the error from trying to parse bad json is a `ValueError`, not a `JSONDecodeError`

```
import requests, time, random

def get_submission_records(client, since, try_number=1):
    url = 'http://reymisterio.net/data-dump/api.php/submission?filter[]=form,cs,'+client+'&filter[]=date,cs,'+since
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, ValueError):
        time.sleep(2**try_number + random.random()*0.01) #exponential backoff
        return get_submission_records(client, since, try_number=try_number+1)
    else:
        return response['submission']['records']
```

so just change that `except` line to include a `ValueError` instead of `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: yes, I was very confused when I was receiving html output. thanks ! this example look great, I'll try it out. hope the header parameter fixes this.

Comment: I have been testing this implementation and I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecodeError'. I am using python 2.7, is it because of this?

Comment: @mateocam oh yes, in Python 2.7, the error is a `ValueError`, I'll update my answer, but basically you should `except` a `ValueError` instead of `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: thanks !! this was so helpful, thank you very much!!

Comment: I used your answer, but got the following error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decoder'". Should it be json.JSONDecodeError instead of json.decoder.JSONDecodeError? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#exceptions)

Comment: @Edgar do you not get that same error if you use `json.JSONDecodeError` instead? The two are equivalent in my version of Python at least, but I think you're right that removing the `decoder` part is the recommended way to access the error. However from the looks of that error you're getting, you might have named a variable `json`, which would overwrite the `json` library.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. it might work

```
while True:
        try:
            submissions = requests.get('http://reymisterio.net/data-dump/api.php/submission?filter[]=form,cs,'+client+'&filter[]=date,cs,'+since).json()['submission']['records']
            sub = json.loads(submissions.text)
            print(sub)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: At least you can say that you add `sub = json.loads(submissions.text)` line.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho is that like a participation trophy?